# How can I split the Klein-Gordon equation into first order ODEs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, differential-equations

The Klein Gordon eqution in conformal time without perturbations is:

[image]

I want to solve the equation numerically, but to do so I need to split it into 2 first order differential equations. What would it look like?

So far I have $\psi_{1}'= \psi_2$
and $\psi_{2}' = -2(a'/a)\psi_2$

Comment: Do the same thing you always do: define a new variable $v = \psi'$.

Comment: This does not look like a second order equation. What is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set $x_1 = \psi$ and $x_2 = \frac{d\psi}{dt}$. Then it's clear that $\frac{dx_1}{dt} = x_2$ and $\frac{dx_2}{dt}=-2 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} x_2$ (this is the equation you gave). You can write this as a matrix equation as follows:
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{dx_1}{dt} \\ \frac{dx_2}{dt} \end{matrix} \right] \ = \ \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & - \frac{2\dot{a}}{a} \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \right]
$$

Comment: Oh I just edited my comment with my own attempt and it looks like it matches, thank you for your help.